# Profile a Gnome Shell extension

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, javascript

An extension I'm working on is having [severe performance issues](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/issues/433), causing the screen or gnome to freeze and other issues.

I'd like to fix it, but I have no idea how or where to start. Is there a way to monitor and profile shell extensions? If not, what is a good way to approach this problem? Will I have to disable features until the lag stops? Or will I have to do the profiling by logging a lot of timestamps?

Comment: Don't you get any error messages in LookingGlass ?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Everything works (kind of) fine

Comment: Well, if there's nothing useful in the `journal` either then the only thing that comes to mind is [`gdb`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Debugging). If that fails to produce anything useful  then you'll prolly have to remove features/modules from your extension to isolate the problem.